# A man pulling a rope standing on the carpet given friction coefficient and tensile force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction

A man is standing on the carpet that lays on the floor. The coefficient of the friction between carpet and floor is `µ = 0.5`. But the coefficient between man and carpet is much more bigger. The thickness of the carpet is very small.

A rope is attached to the wall at a distance of `l = 10m` from the man. The rope is attached at the height of the man arms `h0 = 1m`.
Man is standing in the middle of the carpet. Carpet's `S = 25m2` and man's m=70kg.

*Solve the following questions*:

1. With what force does man have to pull the rope so that the carpet begins to slide?
2. If man squat down and now the level of his arms would be of a height `h1 = 0.2m` above the floor. What the force would he need then?
3. How long would the rope be just before sliding of carpet begins, if its initial length is `l0 = 10 m` and the stiffness coefficient `k = 640 N/m?`

*Note*: I am 8-th grade student. It is 8-9th grade competition's question. We have not studied at school anything about friction / forces / Nuton etc. yet, but I need it for competition. I am studying it on my own. Please, give me some clues, so I can dig deeper.

*My attempt*:

1. I think that if coefficient of friction between man and carpet is very very big, then we can skip it, right? Then the carpet starts to move at some point. We should take only friction between carpet and floor. We can imagine that man is part of carpet (it is one point). And the whole action is horizontally.

So, I have found that in this case could be F=μmg, could it be so? `F=0.5 * 70 * 9.8=343N`, could it be just it or something else is needed here?

2. This is more difficult, because now the rope is hold at some angle. I understand that this affects the angle of force. <strike>But how we proceed in this case? How we should take the angle into account. In 8th grade we have not yet learned sin/cos, but I in general know. Should I somehow use triangle formulas with sin/cos here?</strike>  Am I right that now `F = μ mg * sinα`, so I need to find angle between man and rope α?
3. I have found that tensile force is calculated with the formula F = k ∆l. Nothing more yet.

[image: Man with a rope on the carpet]

Comment: You have a legit question about physics, but as it's stated now it's clearly "how do I solve this exercise" type.

Comment: Maybe it is like that. But I have never lesson about forces and even cos/sin, so I already spent days and days reading about "what is force" and "what is cos/sin". After reading all the material I have found these formulas and I understand basic idea. However, I am not sure if my understanding is right.

Comment: I don't understand -- How do you get the rope to stand on the carpet?

Comment: You are standing on the carpet in the middle, the rope is attached to the wall in front of you 10m further of you, and somehow you get the end of the rope into your hands :) The rope is at the same height from floor as your hands are from the floor.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question the answer is right because we do not care about the friction coefficient between the person and the carpet if we know it is much bigger than the one between the carpet and the floor.

For the second question you are again right in that you need to find the angle between the rope and the floor. The form of the expression is not right however, it should be $F ={ m*g*\mu \over cos\alpha}$.

The last expression for the third question is right, you just have to get the length from it.

Comment: I only partly understand why there is cos and not sin. I will think about it.For 3rd - which F should I use?

Comment: @renathy it's cos because $cos \alpha= {\text{adjacent segment} \over hypotenuse}$ and in our case the adjacent side to the angle is what we care about as that is the direction of the force that it needs to be overcomed(the force of friction between floor and carpet).  For the third question you could use either one, so if it does not specify you could do both.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).